How can I use pytest to see if a class attribute attribute exists in python?
I'm a tech teacher, trying to learn how to use pytest to create specialty koans for my students to learn python syntax. (If you check a previous question, I have details as to what's going on here.)
I'm familiar with test driven development, but predominantly with JavaScript/jQuery. I'm also less familiar with OOP when it comes to python syntax, and now I have to teach it to my students (best way to learn and all that, apparently).
I'm fairly sure I'm writing my code correctly as the command line tests are working, but I need to use TDD for this to work, as my students don't have access to the command line and must run the code in the browser-based code system.
I've tried using hasattr(), but it's always returning False, even when it shouldn't be, assuming I've used it correctly.
The code for the class is such:
class Dog:
  def __init__(self, name, breed):
    self.name = name
    self.breed = breed

The code for the test is in another file, and looks like this:
from utils.attribute_1 import Dog


def test_Dog():
  assert hasattr(Dog, 'name')

So what I've done above is import the class, Dog, from the file, and set up a test function that should show that I have the attribute "name" attached.
When I run it, it returns False. It should be showing True. I'm not sure what I've done wrong, and I'm fairly sure it's going to be a "Problem exists between keyboard and chair" incident, but I'm confused as to how this should work in practice.

Perhaps you want to be testing for attributes on instances of your class?

@Priyank possibly. But when I tried making a fixture it failed pretty epically. I'll see if I can do it again, but I'll be honest when I say I'm not super experienced with fixtures. (The state says I have to teach python, but I'm more skilled in JavaScript.)

Python class definitions keep instance attributes at arm's length. name isn't defined by the class statement itself, only by the assignment that takes place when Dog.__init__ is eventually called on a new instance of Dog.

Your *class doesn't have a name attribute. That is an instance attribute

The code you have provided checks for the attribute on the class Dog itself, and not an instance of the class Dog.
In python, classes are objects of type type. So in your test code you are checking if an object of type type has the attribute name. From your description, you want to test if an object of class Dog has the attribute name. To do that, first you need to create an object of class Dog. Your test should look like:
from utils.attribute_1 import Dog


def test_Dog():
  my_pet = Dog('tuffy', 'pomeranian')  # creating an object of class Dog
  assert hasattr(my_pet, 'name')

It also a good idea to test if the object you created has the expected value - the above test could have passed if objects of type type had the attribute name and you would have been none the wiser.
from utils.attribute_1 import Dog


def test_Dog():
  my_pet = Dog('tuffy', 'pomeranian')  # creating an object of class Dog
  assert hasattr(my_pet, 'name')
  assert my_pet.name == 'tuffy'


just to expand, I believe the only non-dunder attribute inherited from type is .mro which is a method

(Extended commentary on Priyank's answer.)

Classes aren't (directly) responsible for the attributes an instance of the class has. Consider the following:
class Dog:
    pass

d = Dog()  # hasattr(d, 'name') returns False
d.name = "fido"  # hasattr(d, 'name') now returns True

Instance attributes are only created upon definition, and are independent of the class itself. (In some sense, the class is just another attribute of the object, though one whose value affects many things you do with the object.)
In order to avoid having to explicitly create attributes for every instance you create, you can define an __init__ method for the class, which gets called implicitly when you create the object.
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, breed):
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed

d = Dog("fido", "pomeranian")  # d gets created first, then passed to Dog.__init__

You can see this a little more clearly if you override __new__, not just __init__:
class Dog:
    def __new__(cls, name, breed):
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        print("New dog created")
        # __init__ hasn't been called yet
        assert not hasattr(obj, 'name')
        assert not hasattr(obj, 'breed')
        print("Returning new dog")
        return obj

    def __init__(self, name, breed):
        print("Setting name and breed attributes")
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed

d = Dog('fido', 'pomeranian')
# Output
# New dog created
# Returning new dog
# Setting name and breed attributes

Calling Dog(n, b) is (mostly) equivalent to
d = Dog.__new__(Dog, n, b)
d.__init__(n, b)

How (or even if) the __init__ method is called is implemented in type.__call__: D is an instance of type, and so D(n, b) == D.__call__(n, b) == type.__call__(D, n, b). That's as far down the rabbit hole as I will go here.

Thank you for expanding! I'll keep this in mind when I'm explaining to my students.
